# Issues Removing Windows 10 'Modern' Apps

Tags: windows

Windows 10 Enterprise 64 bit. Want to remove modern apps.
Started powershell as admin.

The command I tried was `Get-AppxPackage Microsoft.XboxApp | Remove-AppxPackage`.

The apps just sit there mocking me and don't remove. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does the powershell window show any indication of progress? Have you tried restarting Windows after running the command?

Comment: Hi, Powershell windows has no indication of performing the task at hand- it just lets you enter another command. They are still there after a restart.